# Subscribing to a Photo Stream in iPhoto 11

Tags: icloud, photos.app, photo-stream

I've been struggling to view photos from a subscribed photostream in iPhoto 11.
I'm running OS X 10.7.5 and iPhoto 11 9.4.3 and I've been following [this guide](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH11959):

> To subscribe to a shared photo stream:
>   To subscribe to a shared photo stream, all you have to do is accept the invitation. Invitations to a shared photo stream are sent by email and notifications.
>
> In the Source list, select Photo Stream.
>
> In the lower portion of Photo Stream view, move the pointer over the shared photo stream’s key photo, and then click the Accept button.
>
> If you don’t want to subscribe to the shared photo stream, click the Decline button.
>
> Photo Stream invitation buttons
>   Shared photo streams that you subscribe to appear in the lower portion of Photo Stream view. A blue dot next to the shared photo stream’s name indicates that new photos have been added to the photo stream or new comments have been added to one of its photos. In addition, a number appears above the iPhoto icon in the Dock to indicate that new photos and comments have been shared with you.

I don't have a `lower portion of the screen`.

I've checked with multiple Photo Streams but nothing show's up. How do I regain my lower portion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Edit*: I failed to notice that the poster is on OS X 10.7.5, and Shared Photo Streams require OS X 10.8.2 or later. Therefore it will not work unless the OS is updated. I am leaving the below answer for others to reference.

---

The lower portion of the screen is the section under "Family and Friends' Photos". It's just lower than the "My Photos" section.

Assuming you're already subscribed to the other person's Photo Stream, you would just double-click on the shared stream to open it and view photos.

[image: iPhoto showing the Photo Stream source]

If nothing appears here for you, ensure that you have Photo Stream turned on in iCloud settings. Go to Applications > System Preferences and click on iCloud. Check the box for Photo Stream. Click the Options button and check box boxes on this screen.

[image: System Preferences, iCloud pane, Photo Stream Options]

To turn Photo Stream on, go to iPhoto menu > Preferences and click on the Photo Stream tab. Check all applicable boxes.

[image: iPhoto Preferences showing the Photo Stream tab]

Comment: I don't have a my photos section. I get to photostream from selecting it from recent in the source list. Photostream doesn't appear in "web"

Comment: I added some things to check to ensure you have it completely turned on.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the Shared Photo Streams option in my iPhoto preferences.

Comment: Sorry I don't know why this didn't dawn on me earlier. Shared Photo Streams require OS X 10.8.2 or later.

Comment: I just got that too :)

Comment: Done - I'm going to leave the rest of the answer as things for others to check, but I added a note at the top about OS compatibility.

Comment: for context reason why this had disappeared was I had someone 'fix' my MBP for me. I just assumed they reinstalled correct version. *facepalm*